# Make an object/image appear and disappear randomly in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have to make a target appear and disappear randomly, e.g. in a space of 20 seconds but want to fix the flash first. The object is inserted programmatically and is just a png with collision. When the ball hits it, it disappears and the score is added. This part already works. Current code below

Spawn the enemy(is part of the function for the other 4 enemies)

```
let enemy1 = UIImageView(image: nil)
        enemy1.image = UIImage(named: "enemy2.png")
        enemy1.frame = CGRect(x: w*0.85, y: h*0.035, width: w*0.12, height: h*0.22)
        self.view.addSubview(enemy1)
```

Add 1 to score when hit:

```
 collisionBehaviour = UICollisionBehavior(items:[enemy1])
    dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(collisionBehaviour)

    collisionBehaviour.action = {

        for boulderView in self.bouldersArray{
            if boulderView.frame.intersects(enemy1.frame){
                //enemy1.removeFromSuperview()
                if enemy1.superview != nil{
                        self.scoreCount += 1
                        self.scoreCountLabel.text = "Score: \(self.scoreCount)"
                        enemy1.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's very hardcoded, please don't fix that. Tried an `if` statement to make it appear and disappear from subview, but it didn't work at all, just failed madly.

Answer (score 0):

To make it disappear, set the alpha property to 0

```
enemy1.alpha = 0
```

To make it appear, set the alpha property to 1

```
enemy1.alpha = 1
```

if you wish to animate the disappearing use UIView Animate method

```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.enemy1.alpha = 0
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This doesn't help, I need to get the objects to randomly appear and disappear from subview more than once just consistantly